# Host name for Impala ODBC driver

Tags: odbc, impala

I'm very new to this field and trying to configure a impala odbc driver. On the Cloudera website they say the default host name should be localhost, and the port is 21050.

I tried to use both my local ip address and "localhost" itself, but they don't work. The error message is
[Cloudera][DriverSupport] (1110) Unexpected response received from server. Please ensure the server host and port specified for the connection are correct and confirm if SSL should be enabled for the connection.

Can someone give me some advice on solving the problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is the cloudera server insralled? in  your local machine? Also, port can be anything, please contact cloudera admin for all these info. Sometime authentication can cause problem. Connect to admin on how to connect.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use hostname instead of ip. For example, hostname gs-server-1039 map to 10.200.22.11, you should set gs-server-1039 as impala host not 10.200.22.11.